# How can I use a trigger for populating 3 tables based on another table (populated with 'load data infile')?

Tags: mysql, triggers, stored-functions

I have a final project for a MySQL class so I have the following requests:

I have a table called tab_interm with the following columns:

```
DateVisit varchar(50),
hourentering time,
SnamePatient varchar(100),
FnamePatient varchar(100),
SNameDoctors varchar(100),
FnameDoctors varchar(100),
Cabinet varchar(100));
```

The data for populating this table are in a file.txt.

So I have to create a trigger which populates the following tables:

```
Pacients (id_pacient int auto_increment PK, Sname varchar(50), fname varchar(50))
Cabinets (id_cabinet int auto_increment PK, name) and 
visits (datehourvisits datetime, id_doctor, id_patient, id_cabinet, last 3 being FK).
```

The table doctors (id_doctor, sname, fname) is already populated.

The FK in visits will be populated using last_insert_id().

The trigger will also call a stored function that will transform datavisit and hourentering into a datetime column (probably with str_to_date and concat)
Also I have to declare a continue handler which is activated when a duplicated value is inserted.

I really don't know how to start this trigger. Maybe you will have an idea... thank you.

Comment: Well, first you should check the manual for the [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html). Pretty much is self-explaining then. When the syntax is clear, it pretty much just boils down to writing some insert statements. stack overflow is no code writing service. Have a try, explain your problem well, if you encounter any.

Comment: Actually, the insert part I already did it. What gives me a hard trouble is how the call the function that has the arguments the 2 columns of Tab_interm (DateVisit, hourentering time). I know I should use some variables defined inside the the trigger that calls the function, but how? :(

Comment: To create a datetime out of a date and time, just connect the two with `concat()`, like `concat(DateVisit, ' ', hourentering)` (note the space in between). If your DateVisit is in some weird (non-standard) format, you can use `STR_TO_DATE()`. Again, it's all in the manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).